# ImproperlyConfigured: Field name `address` is not valid for model `User`

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am trying to overide Djoser User registration serializer to add a custom field to user model. Following is my models.py

```
from django.db import models


class User(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
```

and my serializers.py looks like follwing:

```
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer as BaseUserRegistrationSerializer


class UserRegistrationSerializer(BaseUserRegistrationSerializer):
    class Meta(BaseUserRegistrationSerializer.Meta):
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'email', 'first_name', 'address', 'password')
```

and this is my view.py

```
from User.models import User
from User.serializers import UserRegistrationSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserRegistrationSerializer
```

I have configured Djoser configurations in setting.py in following way

```
DJOSER = {
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create': 'User.serializers.UserRegistrationSerializer',
    },
}
```

I am getting following error when I try to create a new user
[image]

I ran makemigration and migrate but error is still there. any help is appreciated :)

**Update**

I have changed my model file. here is new models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

Now i am getting following error
[image]

Comment: @kshikama here is the trace and changed model.

Comment: user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
add on_delete attribute in your user field in Profile model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @kshikama Mentioned in his answer, You should not inherit User model from django.conrib.auth.models.User. So what you can do is to install `django-custom-user` ([django-custom-user](https://github.com/jcugat/django-custom-user)) using pip and use its `AbstractUser` Model.

Also, you are using djoser for auth endpoints. And you have also overridden the `user_create` serializer. So I would suggest that you should not make your own Class based view for User Create. Just override the djoser serializer (which you already have done) and use its endoint.

In your urls. Just include djoser urls.

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^api/auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    ...
]
```

Djoser endoint for user create is `api/auth/users/create/`. For more info please go to [djoser docs](http://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Answer (score 0):

Django already has its own [User model](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L356) defined. If you want to add the address field to it you need to extend it. I usually call the extension "Profile" but you can name it anything you want.

```
class Profile(Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
```

Edit: As suggested by Daniel Roseman in the comments.

Comment: what is `User` here?

Comment: django.contrib.auth.models.User

Comment: No. You should not inherit from User directly. Either inherit from AbstractUser (and set AUTH_USER_MODEL to your subclass), or create a separate Profile with a one-to-one relationship with User.

Comment: @kshikama smae problem with your soultion.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Ah yes, I forgot about that part. Updated with your latter suggestion.

Comment: TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'

Comment: Can you create a new question for that? It sounds like a different problem. Make sure to include a trace.

Comment: @kshikama i have edited the question. please check :)

Comment: exaclt same error, django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Field name `address` is not valid for model `User`.